# How to auto increment bill no

Tags: php, codeigniter

Design page code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control "  placeholder="Bill.No"name="billno" id="AcNo" value="" required>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/get_AcNo",
            data:{id:$(this).val()},
            datatype:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#AcNo").val(res);
                    alert(ok);

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Controller code:

```
public function get_AcNo()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(no) AS `AcNo` FROM `salesbill` ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();

        //print_r($query);
    if($query['AcNo'] == "")
    {
        $message = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $message = $query['AcNo']+1;
    }

    echo json_encode ($message); 
}
```

My problem is the bill no is constantly showing 2 how to auto increment the bill no once the form is submited

Comment: why you are encoding the return data in your controller when ther there is only one variable ?

Comment: auto_increment can be done at DB level. However in this case your value is not updated as jquery deals with static value. Need to use `$(document).on()...` for run time values

Comment: Do it at the DB level like @Riad suggests, after you do an insert get the last inserted id.  What I commonly do is when a "new" record link is clicked I generate a blank record, and pass off the primary key (auto increment) and then auto-save with on-select and on-keypress events for some areas and a save button for others.  Cron job deletes any blank record (no user added data) more than 24 hours old...

Comment: can you explain what was the requirement?you have did this for `$message ` variable  `$query['AcNo']+1`. Which means you need to add +1 when it is not empty?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TipUp_Loan/get_AcNo",
            data:{id:$(this).val()},
            datatype:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#AcNo").val(data);
                    alert(ok);
            }
        });

    });



public function get_AcNo()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(no) AS `AcNo` FROM `salesbill` ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();
    //print_r($query);

    if ($query['AcNo'] == ""){
        $message = 1;
    } else {
        $message = $query['AcNo']+1;
    }
    echo $message; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>TipUp_Loan/get_AcNo",
            data:{id:$(this).val()},
            datatype:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#AcNo").val(data);
                    alert('ok');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

public function get_AcNo()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(no) AS `AcNo` FROM `salesbill` ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();
    //print_r($query);

    if ($query['AcNo'] == ""){
        $message = 1;
    } else {
        $message = $query['AcNo']+1;
    }
    echo $message; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql query:
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(no) AS "AcNo" FROM "salesbill"')->row_array();
or you can try this query as well:
 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT count(no) AS "AcNo" FROM "salesbill"')->row_array();